# Custom Object/ Custom List Object

Tags: c#, oop

I got a question. So I created a custom object in my ProductRec class. 
My custom object:

```
Public Class ProductRec{

public List<Product> Products{get; set;}
}
```

In my method I got two lists. The class of my lists are `List<ProductRec>` and a `List<Product>`.

I would like to add the `List<Product>` into the `List<ProductRec>`. Is there any way to declare the custom object in `List<ProductRec>` and add `List<Product>` into?

What I tried:

```
List<ProductRec> PRList = new List<ProductRec>();

List<Product> myPList = new List<Product>();

Foreach(var h in PRList){
                h.Product = myPList;
}
```

***Note***: There's a list of data in myPList but there's no data in myPRList

My question is: 
Is there any way to declare the custom List object so I can add myPList into PRList.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're trying to do, every item in your PRList should have the same full PList?

Comment: You could implement an [implicit cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) in `ProductRec`, but I'm really failing to see why you don't just create an instance of ProductRec using [object initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) or a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) and then add that to `PRList`.

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile. Please submit code that compiles - it will help getting an answer.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Hi, I'm trying to pass myPList to PRList's custom object (List<Product> Products {get; set;})

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab here based on your comment.  Looks like you just declared a list of `ProductRec` when you meant to just have a single item.

```
ProductRec pr = new ProductRec();
List<Product> myPList = new List<Product>();
pr.Products = myPList;
```

If you intended to have a list of objects that each have their own list, you're lacking a lot of information in your question.